# Tool for drawing UI Mockups for a web application

Tags: user-interface, mockups

One of my clients have asked me to give UI mockups of all pages of my web application...

I found [Balsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/) which seems to be a good one... Any other tools....

- What would you use for drawing UI mockups?

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408202/what-collaborative-wireframing-ui-mockup-tools-are-out-there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SketchFlow](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/SketchFlow_OverView.aspx)?

Answer (score 7):

Check out [Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn/). It can run as a Firefox addon or standalone application.

From its homepage:

> The Pencil Project's unique mission is
>   to build a free and opensource tool
>   for making diagrams and GUI prototyping that everyone can use.

Answer (score 5):

Pencil and paper, scanned if digital is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Online tool http://gomockingbird.com/

Answer (score 2):

[WireframeSketcher](http://wireframesketcher.com) is a tool that helps quickly create wireframes, mockups and prototypes for desktop, web and mobile applications. It comes both as a **standalone** version and as a **plug-in** for Eclipse IDEs. It has some distinctive features like storyboards, components, linking and vector PDF export. Among supported IDEs are are Aptana, Flash Builder, Zend Studio and Rational Application Developer.

[image: Sample WireframeSketcher mockup]
<sub>(source: [wireframesketcher.com](http://wireframesketcher.com/samples/Website.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

[ForeUI](http://www.foreui.com/) is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

[Denim](http://dub.washington.edu:2007/denim/) is interesting and can even run the prototyped webapp with the "hand-drawn" UIs.

(Though I'd also really suggest Balsimiq as the one you should use.)

Answer (score 1):

[**Edraw MAX 5**](http://www.edrawsoft.com/EDrawMax.php) is also a good candidate. Checkout few mockups i made with it.

http://www.mixedwaves.com/2010/03/wireframe-samples-for-poll

Comment: @Penuel great one wish i had this answer earlier...