# FREE Mockup Tool for Web Applications?

Tags: java, web-applications, mockups

what is the best FREE mockup tool for web applications?
I know balsamiq, which is really nice, but lacks the feature of linking different pages together.

I would like to do some kind of prototyping, so not just mocking a view, but also providing interaction between the mockups.

Which tool could I start with?

Comment: Since Version 1.6, Balsamiq is able to link between Mocks: http://blogs.balsamiq.com/product/2009/04/15/mockups-16-release-linking-mockups-and-more/

Comment: Bunch of tools are listed in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219692/tool-for-drawing-ui-mockups-for-a-web-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think exhibit from mit csail is a good choice.
http://simile-widgets.org/exhibit/
You can load your data from javascript and simulate interaction with jquery and/or passing actions through URL parameters.